# listen firebase auth state change with firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i want to listen to firebase auth state changes with provider and if it's signed out it will redirect to login. For the initial it's working fine. If the user signed in it won't have problem to redirect it to home, but when i try to log out and the states change it won't redirect to login.

```
 Future<void> initFirebaseAuth(BuildContext context) async {
    auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      Logger().w('userChanges: $user');
      if (user == null) {
        Logger().w('User is currently signed out!');
        if (!context.mounted) return;
        context.go(SignInScreen.route);
      } else {
        Logger().w('User is signed in!');
        if (!context.mounted) return;
        context.go(HomeScreen.route);
      }
    });
  }
```

the provider called in splash screen

```
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  static const route = '/splash';

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AppProvider>().initFirebaseAuth(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('SplashScreen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[AuthStateChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html) is stream itself and you can use it as follows by pushing this page after the splash page:

```
class CheckPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckPoint({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomePage();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(body: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
        }
        return SignInPage();
      },
    ),
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've used this before but since im using named route now with go router i cannot use this anymore